# detect firefox users on mac only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*EDIT ^^ THIS QUESTION IS DIFFERENT ...

Im using this code below to detect if users are on Firefox, but I want to take it one level farther and only target mac users on Firefox, any advice?

```
var FF = !(window.mozInnerScreenX == null);
    if(FF) {
        // is firefox 
    } else { 
        // not firefox 
    }
```

Comment: that question is similar but i need to detect browser and os together.

Comment: then just do another if statement inside is firefox to check if mac or not and then if not break out

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/11752084/938822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do them separately:

```
var FF = !(window.mozInnerScreenX == null);

if(FF) {
    if(navigator.platform.indexOf('Mac')>=0)
    {
        // is a mac and on firefox
    }
```

I do not have a Mac so I can not test this, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the navigator.appversion call and check for the OS strings.

An example looks like this.

```
navigator.appversion
"5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
```