# What is the correct way to determine whether the paste short cut is 'ctrl + v' or 'cmd + v'

Tags: javascript, windows, macos

I need to show users that to paste they need to do it using keyboard commands. However, the paste command is different on Mac as it is on Windows and I need to be able to detect that. What is the correct way of doing this in **JavaScript** WITHOUT having to do OS checks (as that can be faked, thus why we no longer do browser checks)

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look to this question; [How does one capture a Mac's command key via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript)

If you detect the `window.navigator.platform` of the user, it will tell you which platform the user is using. You can read up on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527983/best-way-to-detect-mac-os-x-or-windows-computers-with-javascript-or-jquery).

Summarizing, you can detect it like this:

```
var isMacLike = navigator.platform.match(/(Mac|iPhone|iPod|iPad)/i);
var isIOS = navigator.platform.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/i);

if(isMacLike || isIOS ){
  //MAC (remove isIos if you dont care about iphone/ipod/ipad)
}
else{ //other O.S.
  //close button on right side
}
```

Comment: How does this apply to the question? He can't make the user type the short-cut and then detect it. He wants to *teach* the user.

Comment: He wants to detect copy/paste through key detections, and thats a way of detect the cmd key, isnt ? If he successfully detect a cmd key, means you have an Mac, right ? Thats the way I understood it