# Creating a CSV file with links to local files

Tags: node.js, excel, csv, excel-formula, export-to-csv

I would like to pragmatically create a CSV and link local files.  When I create the file I will be creating a zip that will contain the csv file as well as the files that I want to link to.

I know that csv does not specify a format for hyperlinks as its just a text file.  However after a little research I found I can do something like this:

```
A1: =CELL("filename")
A2: =LEFT(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUT(A1,"\","")))))
A3: =HYPERLINK(A2 & "brn-0001.xlsx")
```

However this does not work on a mac as the path separator is "/" not "\".  Is there a way to get the path separator in Excel.

Is this really my only option?  Other than never using CSV ;)

Comment: Programatically? Which platform? You've ruled out VBA below even that would be the obvious one.

Comment: I am creating the csv file in a nodejs server.  Output is just raw csv from my web client.  But it should not matter where I create the csv.  Because it can be exported on OSX or Windows I need the csv to work with either platform if possible.  Unfortunately there does not seem to be an excel function to ask for the path separator.

Comment: I've added the node.js tag. It would have been handy to know from the start. If I understand correctly node.js runs on a server, so the web client is going to have to explicitly tell it what the OS is. This seems to be a good guide on detecting from the client side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527983/best-way-to-detect-mac-os-x-or-windows-computers-with-javascript-or-jquery Your web app will have to use that to tell node.js what to do

Comment: I can't test with MAC. But with Windows `=HYPERLINK("brn-0001.xlsx")` should also work without any path, if the `brn-0001.xlsx` is in the same directory as the Excel file which contains the formula.