# Detect MacOS, iOS, Windows, Android and Linux OS with JS

Tags: javascript, operating-system

How to detect MacOS X, iOS, Windows, Android and Linux operating system with JavaScript?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I learnt a lot about `window.navigator` object and its properties: `platform`, `appVersion` and `userAgent`. To my mind, it's almost impossible to detect user's OS with 100% sure, but in my case 85%-90% was enough for me.

So, after examining tons of Stack Overflow answers and some articles, I wrote something like this:

```js
function getOS() {
  const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent,
      platform = window.navigator?.userAgentData?.platform || window.navigator.platform,
      macosPlatforms = ['macOS', 'Macintosh', 'MacIntel', 'MacPPC', 'Mac68K'],
      windowsPlatforms = ['Win32', 'Win64', 'Windows', 'WinCE'],
      iosPlatforms = ['iPhone', 'iPad', 'iPod'];
  let os = null;

  if (macosPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
    os = 'Mac OS';
  } else if (iosPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
    os = 'iOS';
  } else if (windowsPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
    os = 'Windows';
  } else if (/Android/.test(userAgent)) {
    os = 'Android';
  } else if (/Linux/.test(platform)) {
    os = 'Linux';
  }

  return os;
}

alert(getOS());
```

Inspiration:

1. [What is the list of possible values for navigator.platform as of today?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877924/what-is-the-list-of-possible-values-for-navigator-platform-as-of-today)
2. [Best way to detect Mac OS X or Windows computers with JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527983/best-way-to-detect-mac-os-x-or-windows-computers-with-javascript-or-jquery)
3. [How to detect my browser version and operating system using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript)
4. [How to detect Browser and Operating System Name and Version using javaScript](http://code2care.org/pages/detect-browser-and-operating-system-name-and-version-using-javascript/)

Also I used the lists of mobile and desktop browsers to test my code:

1. [List of all Mobile Browsers](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/)
2. [List of all Browsers](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browserlist/)

This code works properly. I tested it on all the OS: MacOS, iOS, Android, Windows and UNIX, but I can't guarantee 100% sure.

Comment: Why not just use "Mac" for MacOS? Should be more future proof.

Comment: Nice solution! Good job! :)

Comment: You should add `"darwin"` to `macosPlatforms`

Comment: I think you need to use userAgent instead of platform for Chrome OS, because in Chrome OS the platform is Linux

Comment: Why do you say "I've wrote something like this" ? I wonder what the actual code do you use and why does it differ from the one here.

Comment: `iosPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1` Can be written more distinctly as `iosPlatforms.includes(platform)`.  It also looks like you could use string matching instead to be more generic `platform.toLowerCase.startsWith("win")`.  You can also eliminate mutating variables by using return in each if conditions (`return 'Windows'` ).

Comment: When running on an iPad pro in emulator this returns Mac OS.

Comment: Isn't time to update this since "navigator.platform" is deprecated? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/platform

Comment: Navigator.userAgentData is still not fully supported - it doesn't work on Firefox, Safari or Internet Explorer. It seems slightly ironic that it says this on Mozilla's website.

Comment: As of OS X Monterey window.navigator?.userAgentData?.platform returns 'macOS'.

Comment: return null for M1 MBP