# Style scrollbar only on windows, not on mac

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to differentiate between styling scrollbars on windows and on mac?

On mac scrollbars looks nice, but on windows look like a crap.

I tried to use:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 10px;
   background: blue;
}
```

But it also affects the nice scrollbar on mac. I dont want it to affect the mac's scrollbar, only this crappy one on windows.
Is it possible?

Comment: Only way I know of would be something based on the user agent. You could do this server-side, or you could do it client side by checking `navigator.userAgent`. For example you could add a class to your style, and only add that class to the body tag if the user agent matches windows.

Comment: Are you using the same browser on each operating-system? What browser and what versions of Windows & macOS are you using?

Comment: Please look to my solution

Answer (score 3):

1 way of doing it is to detect if the user uses not mac device, if yes, add an additional class to the element where you have a scroll that will apply that features. Besides, do not forget to replace IN CSS ".element" with your block where you have the scrollbar.

Example:

```js
function custom_scrollbar(){

   var mac = /(Mac|iPhone|iPod|iPad)/i.test(navigator.platform);
        
    if (mac) return;

   document.getElementById("ELEMENT BLOCK WITH SCROLLBAR HERE").classList.add("edited_scrollbar");
      }

custom_scrollbar();
```

```css
.element.edited_scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
   //Scrollbar properties here.
   
}
```

Comment: Its nice but I'd prefer a pure css solution:(

Comment: @Patrickkx, unfortunately, there is no perfect solution to detect scroll on mac only yet

Comment: I used the next function to detect the user OS, added it as an HTML attribute e.g. `<html os="windows">` and then I just used pure CSS to design the scrollbar only for windows users e.g. `html[os="windows"] body.....` . https://stackoverflow.com/a/38241481/469161