# React Js How to detect current Operating System

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operating-system, progressive-web-apps

How can I detect the current operating system in my react js PWA project.I have used process.platform but it gives "undefined".Please help

Comment: You can refer this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241480/detect-macos-ios-windows-android-and-linux-os-with-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is `const platform = window.navigator.platform`

Comment: It worked for me can you please give me the possible values for the operating systems

Comment: for windows `Win3, Win64, Windows`

Comment: what is the value for ios

Comment: Macintosh, MacIntel, MacPPC,Mac68K

Comment: for ios mobiles?

Comment: This is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform) now.

Answer (score 0):

**Values for the operating systems:**

const platform = window.navigator.userAgentData.platform;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).