# How to detect if device is iOS, Android or Desktop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to show different app link depends on user operation system.
Such as IOS, Android or both if user is opening page on Desktop.
I'm using React and Next.js
I tried to use navigator.userAgent with no luck.

It will be perfect to achieve code like below:

```
import React from "react";
import { AppDownload as AppDownloadProps } from "xxx";

export default function DownloadApp({
  appDownload,
}: AppDownloadProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
        <div>
          {isIos && <a href={appDownload?.ios.url}></a>}
          {isAndroid && <a href={appDownload?.android.url}></a>}
          {isDesktop && <a href={appDownload?.desktop.url}></a>}
        </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect MacOS, iOS, Windows, Android and Linux OS with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241480/detect-macos-ios-windows-android-and-linux-os-with-js)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `navigator.userAgent` to detect the useragent in browser and there are lots of other options are available to get agent information.

```js
console.log("agent is:", window?.navigator?.userAgent)

console.log("platform is: ", window?.navigator?.platform)

console.log("user agent data: ", window?.navigator?.userAgentData)
```

Comment: This worked for me, i just created an: if (window?.navigator?.platform == "iPhone"){ code if iphone }. You can do the same for each platform.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Detect MacOS, iOS, Windows, Android and Linux OS with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241480/detect-macos-ios-windows-android-and-linux-os-with-js).

You can use `window.navigator` but will need to parse the result.