# Extract text between parenthesis and space using Javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using Javascript to parse the following User-Agent string:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
```

I'd like to extract the word "Windows" between the first parenthesis and a space. How can I use regular expressions in Javascript to do this?

Comment: I feel like regex isn't the best way to do this. Since you just want the word after the first parenthesis, you could find the first instance of `(`, then find the first instance of `[space]` after it, and then take the substring between them.

Comment: If you are looking to perform operations on the User-agent string then I would suggest a battle-tested library might be more suitable than regex.

Comment: Maybe it helps: [Detecting OS Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27862868/6188402)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only one the first word after the first parentheses you can use this regex: `/\((\w+)/g`

```js
var string = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0";

console.log(/\((\w+)/g.exec(string)[1] || 0)
```

Comment: Did you think of strings that won't match your criteria ? Error would be throws as you would be accessing [1] of null.

Comment: Why not using `\w` instead of `[^ ]`? It seems more clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
// Your input string
const string = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0';

// Find string
const match = string.match(/\((.+?)\s/);

// If string was found
if (match !== null) {
  // Get the result
  // match[0] is this whole matched string
  // match[1] is just the matched group
  const result = match[1];
  
  // So something with the result
  console.log(result);
}
```