# What's the value of navigator.platform on ARM Macs?

Tags: javascript, macos

Apple has [released](https://www.apple.com/apple-events/november-2020/) several new computers based on M1 chip which uses ARM architecture (in contrast to previous computers that are based on x86 architecture). What is the value of the `navigator.platform` JavaScript variable in Safari, Chrome and other browsers on the new ARM computers? Also, what's the user agent (it should contain the platform name)?

You can check yours using this snippet:

```js
console.log(navigator.platform);
console.log(navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: Be careful relaying on navigator.userAgent, as there's a proposal to freeze this chaotical string gaining traction

Comment: @netizen, do you mean tracking? If so, then user agent is bad for tracking because it’s very easy to mock for ordinary users.

Comment: No, I mean that my browser userAgent is saying that is Mozilla (it is not), Safari (no, also not safari). Check [this proposal](https://github.com/WICG/ua-client-hints)

Answer (score 7):

All Chrome / Chromium-based browsers will return `MacIntel` on macOS, no matter what the hardware architecture is. See the source code here: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/frame/navigator_id.cc;l=64;drc=703d3c472cf27470dad21a3f2c8972aca3732cd6

Comment: And `navigator.appName` will return _'Netscape',_ a browser that's been **dead for 2 decades!**

Answer (score 5):

Tested on my real MacBook Air (M1) and the `navigator.platform` value for Chrome on ARM Macs is still **MacIntel**. I assume that will change in the future, this is just the first version of their M1 build.

Likewise, the user agent is also Intel: `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_0_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36`

If you want to detect if you're on an ARM M1 Mac, you can read the `WebGL Renderer` value which is **Apple M1**.

Comment: Do you get the `WebGL Renderer` value [like this](https://gist.github.com/cvan/042b2448fcecefafbb6a91469484cdf8)?

Comment: WebGL Renderer doesn't work as a test in Safari. While Chrome reports it as "Apple M1" Safari says "Apple GPU" which is exactly what it says on an Intel mac.

Comment: Detection via WebGL Renderer is working as a Chrome-Only feature currently as browsers are trying to avoid detection of platforms. Chrome has 2/3 of the browser viewership at this time so this is not really a bad thing. I made a test page for it here: https://browserstrangeness.github.io/detect_mac.gpu.htm and a mirror here: https://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.io/detect_mac.gpu.htm (I am pretty sure Google didn't intend this as a method of platform detection using Chrome either.)

Answer (score 2):

Tested on my M1 and interestingly enough, **Safari on an M1 also returns MacIntel** for navigator.platform.

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 108 on an M1 (with macOS Big Sur, 11.7.2) also still reports `MacIntel`.

Answer (score 0):

navigator.userAgent:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36

It's up to date MacBook Air with M1 8GPU model. I downloaded M1 version of Chrome from official site.

[image]

[image]