# How to detect Apple Silicon Macs in Cordova App?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ipad, silicon

I'm developing apps with Apache Cordova for iOS and would like to make them available on Macs with Apple Silicon, too.

Although I don't need it right now, I'd like to implement a method to distinguish between iPads running the app and Macs with Apple Silicon in my javascript code.

I came up with the idea of checking `navigator.platform` (which is `iPad` for both platforms) in connection with `navigator.camera.Direction`. My assumption is that all relevant iPads have two cameras (front & back), while Macs should only report a front facing camera (if any). Ipads would report this:

`{BACK: 1, FRONT: 1}`

Macs would report either `{BACK: 0, FRONT: 1}` or `{BACK: 0, FRONT: 0}` (if no camera is available).

Do you think this will work? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Just look at the userAgent and catch the iPAD version and the CPU as well I believe

Comment: userAgent on Apple Silicon: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 17_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148`
userAgent on iPad: `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 17_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148` 

I don't see how that could work, @Eric.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853342/whats-the-value-of-navigator-platform-on-arm-macs