# How to determine browser platform without navigator.platform

Tags: javascript, html

While previously we were able to use `navigator.platform` in order to check which OS a browser was running in (which is still necessary for things like key event translation, e.g. `Home` vs. `metaKey+ArrowLeft`, or placing virtual modal "close" icons in a way that follows OS conventions) that option [no longer exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform). (That is to say, right now [it technically still does](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_navigator_platform) but it's no longer a solution that is guaranteed to work [by the time you deploy your code](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/05/update-on-user-agent-string-reduction.html)).

I can't seem to find any official documentation on what the replacement is supposed to be if OS knowledge is required: what is the new and improved way to determine which OS/platform a web page is running on?

(The currently most popular SO question around this, ["Best way to detect Mac OS X or Windows computers with JavaScript or jQuery"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527983), does not have any answers that have been edited since the decision to deprecate `navigator.platform` was made, so unfortunately is not useful at the moment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the only realistic option for now is to look at the [User Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) string and make decisions based on that (either by handrolling code, or using a user agent parsing library that does that for you).

This is not ideal, but as the goal is OS detection, and explicitly *not* browser detection, it's also not too hacky or liable to break in the future.

Comment: I'm writing integration tests so there are no HTTP requests. What can I do now?

Comment: I'm a little confused how you can write integration tests (i.e. tests with a browser that load your pages and then interact with them, performing tests based  on the system as a whole, as opposed to unit tests) without having anything request pages to run their test actions on?

Comment: actually there are HTTP requests but we just return mock responses to them. So there is no backend

Comment: Still a bit confused then: what's preventing the browser from checking its own user agent?

Comment: hm I don't know maybe it is doable. Can make an HTTP call and give a mock response and then check userAgent? I just used `process.platform` instead

Comment: There is no `process` in the browser, so you're not running browser based integration tests at all (e.g selenium, playwright, etc). You're doing _something_, and you're doing that in Node, but that's all we know at the moment. You could ask Node which OS it's currently running on using `process.platform`, but if you're not even using a browser then just mock the user agent for whatever OS your test is pretending to run for?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be using [`navigator.userAgentData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData) along with the [`.getHighEntropyValues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorUAData/getHighEntropyValues) method. Then we can utilize the [User-Agent Client Hints API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/User-Agent_Client_Hints_API) and get high entropy values from `userAgentData` by requesting a number of hints. Providing a means to detect OS from User-Agent information since `navigator.platform` is no longer.

Or instead just access `navigator.userAgent` which has full support and provides a user-agent string for the current browser where the OS could be extracted from.

```js
function checkOS(n) {
  if (n.userAgentData) {
    const hints = ["architecture", "model", "platform", "platformVersion", "uaFullVersion"];
    n.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues(hints)
      .then(ua => {
        console.log(ua);
      });
  } else {
    console.log(n.userAgent);
    return "navigator.userAgentData is not supported!";
  }
}

checkOS(navigator);
```

This is about the only documentation I've found in the DevTools "issues" tab aside from information on [update on user agent string reduction](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/05/update-on-user-agent-string-reduction.html).

> A page or script is accessing at least one of `navigator.userAgent`, `navigator.appVersion`, and `navigator.platform`. In a future version of Chrome, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced. - To fix this issue, replace the usage of `navigator.userAgent`, `navigator.appVersion`, and `navigator.platform` with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to `navigator.userAgentData`.

I tried logging `navigator.userAgentData` to the console on a Windows and macOS machine using Chrome to see what kind of data it contained, and the object does have some useful information like the `getHighEntropyValues()` method in particular.

```js
// NavigatorUAData {brands: Array(3), mobile: true}
{
  "brands": [
    {
      "brand": "Chromium",
      "version": "92"
    },
    {
      "brand": " Not A;Brand",
      "version": "99"
    },
    {
      "brand": "Google Chrome",
      "version": "92"
    }
  ],
  "mobile": false,
  "getHighEntropyValues": function getHighEntropyValues() { [native code] }
}
```

The [browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.userAgentData) for `navigator.userAgentData` is not great (only supported in Chrome, Edge, Opera), but this could be a step in the right direction for detecting OS from `userAgentData` since `navigator.platform` is no longer. [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/tannerdolby/pen/GRENMrG)

Comment: Yeah, this appears to be yet another one of those Chrome-only solutions instead of a true, agreed upon replacement =(

Comment: Yeah, agreed =(