# Body height changes as I scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was looking to find the top position of my footer. I have tried:

```
$('#footer').offset().top
```

and

```
$(document.body).height() - $('#footer').height()
```

Both of these gave me the same answer but the wrong answer. I have noticed that as I scroll past a certain point in the document the body height (as viewed in Firebug layout) changes from 5699 to 11506.

I have tried setting:

```
body { min-height: 100% }
head { height : 100% }
```

with no success.

My question is why does the body height change and how can I determine the real height of my body or document (or the top position of my footer)?

*Update: weirdly this appears to now work on my Windows >> Firefox & Chrome browsers, but is out by nearly double on my OSX >> Firefox & Chrome browsers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Continue troubleshooting:

```
console.log( $(document.body).height() );
console.log( $(document).height() );
console.log( $('body').height() );
```

See if any one these gives desired values.

I just tried them myself, and noticed different result.

```
$(document.body).height() > $(document).height()
```

So try without the `.body` and see what you get.

Comment: best results achieved using $('body') in Firefox. Will do testing on other browsers soon. Thank

Comment: weirdly this appears to now work on my Windows >> Firefox & Chrome browsers, but is out by nearly double on my OSX >> Firefox & Chrome browsers. Any ideas?

Comment: Keep exploring in OSX, and then do a [solution by OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044944/jquery-javascript-to-detect-os-without-a-plugin).