# Hide CSS element dependant on operating system using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show-hide

I am trying to simply hide/show an element depending if you're on mac, windows, iphone, ipad etc.

I have 2 p elements:
p1 - I want to show on windows
p2 - I want to show on everything else (mac/iphone/ipad etc)

I found a script here that apparently detects operating system: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/07/16/jquery-browser-and-os-detection-plugin/

So I linked to the script after a link to jquery, plus this to the page head:

```
if ($.client.os == 'Mac') {
    $('#download').hide(); $('#register').show();
}

if ($.client.os == 'iPhone') {
    $('#download').hide(); $('#register').show();
}

if ($.client.os == 'Windows') {
    $('#download').show(); $('#register').hide();
}
```

I cannot get it to work, any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `$.client.os`? Any errors?  You may want to look at user agent as opposed to operating system.

Comment: you should add the class of the OS to body tag and hide your stuff in the CSS based on body class

Comment: Are you include jquery.client.js

Comment: @TamilSelvan yes I was including it.

Comment: @Huangism do you have an example of this?

Comment: there are plugins that does this for you but if your current plugin does not support this, then don't worry about it

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044944/jquery-javascript-to-detect-os-without-a-plugin) has some solutions to your problem. Given the properties you're specifying, all you should need to do is:

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) {
    $('#register').hide();
    $('#download').show();
}
```

You shouldn't need to explicitly show elements since the client won't be changing OS. Just set the base visibility of `#download` and `#register` to whatever you 'default' configuration is (put `#download { display: none; }` in your CSS) and let the `.hide()` and `.show()` override them when necessary.

If you need more advanced OS detection, you can add other rules by replacing `"Win"` with an appropriate OS tag.

**EDIT** fixed jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2G4pz/5/

Comment: Thanks metadept but this doesn't make sense if I have 2 elements I would have to hide element 1 and show element 2 if on mac/Ios and then  if on windows hide element 2 and show element 1. Am I making sense here?

Comment: @James Yes, I'm just saying that you don't need to *change* the visibility for every case, you can have things as you want them for Mac by default, and then you only need to change them if the user is on Windows. If you want to explicitly set them that's fine, but it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks I get you, so you're saying as long as I have #download {display:none;} in my css the script above will over-ride this on windows machines and hide #register and show #download ?

Comment: @James Exactly. Here's a (very very simple) jsFiddle that demonstrates what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/2G4pz/3/

Comment: Thanks @metadept I used your above code and tested on a windows machine though and still get the register div and not the download?

Comment: is it perhaps something to do with navigator.platform not being present?

Comment: @James I'll test it on my Windows machine when I get home and update my answer.

Comment: @James ...seems like I had the jsFiddle set up wrong (fixed now in the answer) but the code works (when it's used right :p)

Comment: It works! thanks so much mate, I was just being a little retarded in inserting it properly (javascript amateur here) - thanks for all your help.