# OS Detection in javascript for all the devices and cross-browser

Tags: javascript, dom, web, cross-browser, user-agent

I am working on web analytics, I have to find out the `os` of the visitor specific with following conditions

1.Cross-browser compatibility.

2.For all devices(tablet,iphone,mobile,deskstop,etc).

3.Maximum possible accuracy.

I have referred some questions [regarding os detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044944/jquery-javascript-to-detect-os-without-a-plugin), Answer is `navigator.platform` but it does [not supported for some devices](http://mscerts.programming4.us/programming/coding%20javascript%20for%20mobile%20browsers%20%28part%204%29.aspx)

`Note:` we cannot rely on useragent as well.

Any suggestion will be greatful.

Comment: what about to mix `navigator.platform` and `navigator.userAgent` to fallback if `.platform` returns null or undefined?

Comment: @alexi May be tats is the final workaround if i didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case it could be PHP instead of JavaScript; this piece of code is so reliable and accurate and have been tested on many devices -mobile devices- and it works like charm:

```
preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|nokia|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
```

this only detects mobile devices but you can tweak the code in different way to get what you need.

Also check this link >> [php to detect browser and operating system -](http://www.killersites.com/community/index.php?/topic/2562-php-to-detect-browser-and-operating-system/) which contains PHP codes too.