# How to set default selected QuickTabs tab depending on operating system?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've a D6 website where I'm using QuickTabs to display block content.

A *download* page has a 'Windows' tab and 'Mac OS X' tab - how can I pre-select the tab appropriate to the visitors OS on page load (or default to Windows if no match)?

PS I'm a Drupal novice at best!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use Javascript to detect the user's Operating System and hide/display the correct tabs based on this information.

OS detection:
[jQuery/Javascript to detect OS without a plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044944/jquery-javascript-to-detect-os-without-a-plugin)

Jquery howto with examples:
http://visualjquery.com/

Good luck.