# Can SharePoint display the Operating System being used when a person logs into a team site

Tags: sharepoint, printing, operating-system

We're installing some new printers at our institution, and there would be different drivers for different computer types.

I was wondering if something could be built in SharePoint that when the person logs into our print driver page that it could only display the driver that works for their type of computer?

Answer (score 0):

If your only concerned around the type of Os e.g windows, mac etc.

You can use

```
var os = navigator.platform;
```

This will return something like Win32 for a windows based OS. This could be put in to one of the OOTB web parts (ContentEditorWebPart)

You could place all the links to drivers on a page and show and hide them accordingly with some javascript/ Jquery

[Some more detail in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044944/jquery-javascript-to-detect-os-without-a-plugin)

Cheers

Truez

Comment: Hi Truez, We did try this but it didn't really give us any results.  Can you give me a little more detail of how to make it work in CEWB?